# What is probability of language knowledge in company?

Tags: probability

In a company are 100 workers.

- 50 of them (100) speak ENG
- 30 of them (100) speak GER
- 15 of them (100) speak ENG and GER

What is the probability of randomly selected worker speaks GER on condition he does NOT speaks ENG?

I have two suggestions:

- a) 3/10
- b) lower than 3/10

Comment: Wouldn't the probability just be 1/2 of GER/TOTAL since half of the workers speak english?

Comment: only 30 of 100 workers speak GER so without the ENG condition it would be 3/10 so I believe it shold be lower :)

Comment: Are speaking ENG and GER independent? I would be illogical if it was so, but without assuming that we can't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry now I see my mistake, update in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the problem, a worker speaking German and a worker speaking English are independent events. As such, the fact that a worker speaks English doesn't actually give you any information as to whether or not a worker speaks German. Thus, the odds that a worker speaks German *given* that he speaks English is the same as the odds that a worker speaks German: $\frac{3}{10}$

Comment: I think by "on condition he does speaks ENG" means the worker must speak both GER and ENG, but the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Speaks GER but no ENG = 15 
divided by 
no ENG speaking people 50.

15 / 50 = 0.3

Answer (score -1):

```
ENG          Non-ENG
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺ | ☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺ | ☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺ | ☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☻☻☻☻☻☺☺☺☺☺ | ☻☻☻☻☻☺☺☺☺☺
☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻ | ☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻
```

☻ =  GER

The odds of randomly selecting a GER speaker out of the total are $3/10$ (30 GER out of 100 workers) and half of the workers also speak ENG.

Therefore, the odds of a randomly selected worker speaking GER and not ENG are $1/2$(Fraction of workers that don't speak ENG) times 3/10(fraction of workers that speak GER).

$.15$ or $3/20$

Comment: sorry my mistake, he does NOT speak ENG. But maybe in this case it does not matters :) 50:50

Comment: @Luxqs Same odds then since the number of ENG speakers = Number of non-ENG speakers.

Comment: @Luxqs See the graph I made, the groups are the same.

Comment: can you more deeper write how you get the number like my error calculation ((15/100)/(50/100))

Comment: By your own chart, the answer is 0.3... the question is what is the odds of a black smiley face in the right group. That's 15/50... **-1**.

Comment: I still think its 0.3 :)   speaks GER but no ENG = 15 divided by no ENG speaking people 50. so 15 / 50 = 0.3

Comment: The question was ambiguous. If you are selecting out of the total number of workers, the answer is .15. If you are only selecting from the non english speakers, then the answer is .3. My answer is not wrong given the description in the question. @Luxqs

Comment: Sorry if you are confused, I just got this question from my GFs test and I just translated it. Before that I did also some calculations :)